# How to change a variable that's not inside the parent class when inheriting from it

Tags: python, oop

I have a basic simple example below to show what I'm trying to do.

Here's the file that I'm using but can't change (it's an installed library):

```
treats = 5

class Pet(object):
    def eat(self):
        # Uses the variable 'treats' in this method
```

And here's the file I'm working in:

```
from other_file import Pet

class Dog(Pet):
    # Change the value of 'treats' here
```

I'm trying to change the variable `treats` in my child class for the `eat()` method, without having to override that method.

I'm still a novice when it comes to object-oriented techniques in python and had trouble searching for this particular situation without knowing what exactly to search for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @adamr notes in the comments, you could do this:

```
import other_file
other_file.treats = 12
```

Unfortunately, that will change the value of `treats` for *all* instances of `Pet`. If this doesn't work for you, and given that you can't change `other_file`, your best option as far as I can see is to inherit from `Pet` and also override `eat` to use e.g. `self.treats`.

Comment: Perhaps this is @missmely's intention that for each instance of Pet treats got the same value ;)

Comment: Okay, so that's how it would work. Thankfully, I would like it to change for all instances of Pet :) I did think about overriding the methods themselves that use this theoretical `treats` variable, but there are several of them and they're long and ugly haha. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You're not defining it as a class attribute.

```
class Pet(object):
  def __init__(self, treats):
    self.treats = treats

  def eat(self):
    #

class Dog(Pet):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dog, self).__init__()
        print self.treats
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I cannot change how the file that defines `Pet()` is coded because in my case, it's an installed library.